# curl delete files in a folder from artifactory

Tags: curl, artifactory

I have files in a folders in an artifactory. Is it possible to use curl to remove files older than a certain period using certain keys?

Internal artifactory mechanisms only allow deleting from the remote repository cache. In local repositories this is not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
You can use curl with [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-DateandTimeFormat) to fetch the list of files you wish to delete and use curl to delete each file in the list.

However, a cleaner easier way of doing it would be using the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/).

Using the CLI you can use (as an example) the **delete** command with --sort and --limit a your command options, to [delete your desired files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles),

or if you need more control, use --spec with AQL as your spec file content to control the exact files you'd like to delete.

Comment: To add an example, if you wish to delete files above a certain date, you can use the following command with the cli:
   
   jfrog rt del --spec=mySpecFile --quiet=true

and use the following specfile to specify the date (I use modified, you can use created)

{"files": [{"aql": {"items.find": {"repo": "generic-local","$or": [{"$and": [{"modified": {"$lt": "2018-12-01"}}]}]}}}]}

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for ways to automatically cleanup old artifacts from your local repositories. To do this, you can use the [Artifact Cleanup user plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup).

If plugins are not an option for you (The OSS and Community editions of Artifactory don't support plugins), there isn't really an easy way. You can write a script that uses a combination of [search APIs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SEARCHES) and the [delete API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem) to do what you want. I'm not certain offhand which search APIs are available in the free versions, though.